Spring JPA - Changing the data type of an already established ID?
Long story short, I messed up and need to change an ID from a string to an autogenerated long within Spring and update any children with the newly generated number ID. I'm attempting to correct it with a new Flyway version, but the auto-generated foreign key names that I must delete give me the feeling that they are not the same in production and, in general, should not be touched this way.
What is the appropriate way to make the transition?
Edit : I'm having marginal success by simply moving over to a new version of the id - though as expected, hibernate is failing to create the appropriate constraints to the new id_v2 parent column (I've also created parent_id_v2 in the child).
Error executing DDL "alter table `website$blog` add constraint FK50amru4p1wg4jq0stsw8distc foreign key (website_id_v2) references `website` (id_v2)" via JDBC [Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'FK50amru4p1wg4jq0stsw8distc' in the referenced table 'website'

@Getter @Setter
private String id;
@Getter @Setter @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id_v2;

Edit again : The following seems to solve it, but again, not sure if this is appropriate
@Table(name="store$website", indexes= @Index(name = "idx_store$website_id_v2", columnList = "id_v2"))


Start by adding a new column for the long ID in your entity alongside the existing string ID. Use Hibernate's @GeneratedValue to automatically generate the new ID. Create a migration script in Flyway to populate the new column by converting existing string IDs to long values.
In your entity class -
@Entity
@Table(name = "website")
public class Website {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "id_v2")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idV2;

    // Optionally add a method to help with conversion if needed
    public Long getConvertedId() {
        return Long.parseLong(id);
    }
}

Your Flyway migration script could look like this -
ALTER TABLE website ADD COLUMN id_v2 BIGINT;
UPDATE website SET id_v2 = CAST(id AS BIGINT);
CREATE INDEX idx_website_id_v2 ON website(id_v2);


Is there any way to drop the initial id column, or at least not require it anymore? Leaving @Id in the initial Id field keeps it as the primary key which requires me to give the field data.

I have found it more convenient to simply go the route of creating WebsiteV2 and moving things over there.

Do you mean adding a column like id_v2?

I tried this but I can't simply swap the Id annotation in Spring JPA - nothing truly changes so I'm forced to also put a unique value in the original primary key. I would have to manually remove the foreign keys since the names of the foreign keys are autogenerated, which leaves me unable to simply remove the foreign key within flyway. So, I created a new entity WebsiteV2 with the appropriate fields, rewired everything and simply use an entirely new entity. With the new entity I can create a proper migration with flyway.
